# air of attention

Tags: meaning

I didnt find any definition of this phrase in the internet.
I want to understand it correctly.
Here is the entire text:

> "Here's an alarm now," he exclaimed, all attention. Twice the alarm
>   was repeated, being sent out all over the city. McCormick ***relapsed
>   from his air of attention***."

I would appriciate your help.

Comment: Not every phrase is a set phrase. air of attention is a way to say: attentive air. But the writing is rather poor due to the unneeded repetition of the word attention like that. That paragraph needs help.

Comment: @Lambie And what could that mean? What did he do?

Comment: That is a short story written in 1912! He basically means: lost his air of attention, That is an unusual use of relapse: my attention lapsed. So relapsed would be: to lose attention again.

Comment: @Lambie Thank you a lot! You can't imagine how I was suffering trying to figure it out. Yes it's kind of old story. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

From Oxford Learner's Dictionary (https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/air_1?q=air):

> **Air (n.) impression**
>
> ​[singular] the particular feeling or impression that is given by somebody/something; the way somebody does something
>
> "She looked at him with a defiant air."
>
> **air of something**
>
> "The room had an air of luxury."
>
> There was an air of complete confidence about her.